# fatal error: 'clang/Frontend/FrontendPluginRegistry.h' file not found #include "clang/Frontend/FrontendPluginRegistry.h"

Tags: clang, clang++

[fatal error: 'clang/Frontend/FrontendPluginRegistry.h' file not found
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendPluginRegistry.h"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRR5l.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRR5l.jpg)

Comment: Hello @Muskan, welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [_How do I ask a good question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking questions. Add relevant information about what your error is, with detailed description.

Comment: Install `libclang-dev` using the command `sudo apt install libclang-dev` and try again. It worked for me. If not, let me know.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59888374/12357035) on how to install and setup clang and llvm.