# How to find method declarations in LibTooling?

Tags: clang, llvm, libtooling

I'm writing a program in LibTooling to print information of all functions, including methods in classes. But it seems `VisitFunctionDecl()` only detects functions outside a class. I also tried `VisiCXXMethodDecl()`,

```
bool VisiCXXMethodDecl(CXXMethodDecl *node) {
    string return_type = node->getReturnType().getAsString();
    string function_name = node->getNameInfo().getAsString();
    cout << "function name: " << function_name << endl;
    cout << "return type: " << return_type << endl;
    cout << "has body: " << node->hasBody() << endl;
 }
```

but still failed to detect them. Can anyone tell me what's the correct way to detect methods defined in classes?

Comment: It seems there are macros that hindered the parsing process.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick fix

In your question, you have a typo in the name of the visitor method,
which should be `VisitCXXMethodDecl`, not `VisiCXXMethodDecl` (missing
the `t` in `Visit`).  That may be all that needs fixing, but I can't
tell without seeing the rest of the code.

Note that the compiler will not warn about that sort of typo because
[`RecursiveASTVisitor`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html)
does not use virtual methods to customize its action (if it did, and you
used the [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override)
specifier, then the typo would result in an error).  Instead, it uses
template metaprogramming and static overriding, and in that context, a
typo'd method name just looks like some unrelated method.

### Complete example

Here is a complete program that prints the names and locations of every
C++ method declaration (including definitions) in a translation unit.

`method-decls.cc`:

```
// method-decls.cc
// Print name and location of all method declarations using clang
// libtooling.

#include "clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h"                 // clang::RecursiveASTVisitor
#include "clang/Basic/Diagnostic.h"                        // clang::DiagnosticsEngine
#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticOptions.h"                 // clang::DiagnosticOptions
#include "clang/Frontend/ASTUnit.h"                        // clang::ASTUnit
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"               // clang::CompilerInstance
#include "clang/Serialization/PCHContainerOperations.h"    // clang::PCHContainerOperations

#include <iostream>                                        // std::cout

using std::cout;


class MethodVisitor : public clang::RecursiveASTVisitor<MethodVisitor> {
public:      // data
  clang::ASTContext &m_astContext;

public:      // methods
  MethodVisitor(clang::ASTContext &astContext)
    : m_astContext(astContext)
  {}

  // Visit each method declaration (including definitions).
  bool VisitCXXMethodDecl(clang::CXXMethodDecl *methodDecl);

  // Print all methods in the translation unit.
  void printMethodInfo();
};

bool MethodVisitor::VisitCXXMethodDecl(clang::CXXMethodDecl *methodDecl)
{
  clang::SourceLocation loc = methodDecl->getLocation();

  cout << "C++ method \""
       << methodDecl->getQualifiedNameAsString()
       << "\" at "
       << loc.printToString(m_astContext.getSourceManager())
       << "\n";

  // Continue recursively visiting the children of 'methodDecl'.
  return true;
}


void MethodVisitor::printMethodInfo()
{
  this->TraverseDecl(m_astContext.getTranslationUnitDecl());
}


int main(int argc, char const **argv)
{
  // Point 'LoadFromCommandLine' at the clang binary so it will be able
  // to find its compiler headers such as stddef.h.
  argv[0] = CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR "/bin/clang";

  // Boilerplate setup for 'LoadFromCommandLine'.
  std::shared_ptr<clang::PCHContainerOperations> pchContainerOps(
    new clang::PCHContainerOperations());
  clang::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticsEngine> diagnosticsEngine(
    clang::CompilerInstance::createDiagnostics(
      new clang::DiagnosticOptions));

  // Run the Clang parser to produce an AST.
  std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTUnit> ast(clang::ASTUnit::LoadFromCommandLine(
    argv,
    argv + argc,
    pchContainerOps,
    diagnosticsEngine,
    llvm::StringRef() /*ResourceFilesPath, evidently ignored*/));

  if (ast == nullptr ||
      diagnosticsEngine->getNumErrors() > 0) {
    // Error messages have already been printed.
    return 2;
  }

  MethodVisitor methodVisitor(ast->getASTContext());
  methodVisitor.printMethodInfo();

  return 0;
}


// EOF
```

`Makefile` (based on the one at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72596778/2659307)
of mine, but with a few further refinements):

```
# Makefile

# Default target.
all:
.PHONY: all


# ---- Configuration ----
# Installation directory from a binary distribution.
# Has five subdirectories: bin include lib libexec share.
# Downloaded from: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-14.0.0/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz
CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR = $(HOME)/opt/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04

# ---- llvm-config query results ----
# Program to query the various LLVM configuration options.
LLVM_CONFIG := $(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)/bin/llvm-config

# C++ compiler options to ensure ABI compatibility.
LLVM_CXXFLAGS := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --cxxflags)

# Directory containing the clang library files, both static and dynamic.
LLVM_LIBDIR := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --libdir)

# Other flags needed for linking, whether statically or dynamically.
LLVM_LDFLAGS_AND_SYSTEM_LIBS := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --ldflags --system-libs)


# ---- Compiler options ----
# C++ compiler.
CXX = g++

# Compiler options, including preprocessor options.
CXXFLAGS =
CXXFLAGS += -Wall
CXXFLAGS += -Werror

# Silence a warning about a multi-line comment in DeclOpenMP.h.
CXXFLAGS += -Wno-comment

# Get llvm compilation flags.
CXXFLAGS += $(LLVM_CXXFLAGS)

# Tell the source code where the clang installation directory is.
CXXFLAGS += -DCLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR='"$(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)"'

# Linker options.
LDFLAGS =

# Pull in clang+llvm via libclang-cpp.so, which has everything, but is
# only available as a dynamic library.
LDFLAGS += -lclang-cpp

# Arrange for the compiled binary to search the libdir for that library.
# Otherwise, one can set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH envvar before running it.
# Note: the -rpath switch does not work on Windows.
LDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath=$(LLVM_LIBDIR)

# Get the needed -L search path, plus things like -ldl.
LDFLAGS += $(LLVM_LDFLAGS_AND_SYSTEM_LIBS)


# ---- Recipes ----
# Compile a C++ source file.
%.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $<

# Executable.
all: method-decls.exe
method-decls.exe: method-decls.o
    $(CXX) -g -Wall -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# Quick test.
.PHONY: run-quick
run-quick: method-decls.exe
    ./method-decls.exe test.cc

# Slow test using a realistic source file.  This needs the same
# compilation flags as when compiling.  Also it produces a lot of
# output.
.PHONY: run-slow
run-slow: method-decls.exe
    ./method-decls.exe $(CXXFLAGS) method-decls.cc

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.exe


# EOF
```

`test.cc`:

```
// test.cc
// Quick test of method-decls program.

class C {
public:
  int f1();
  int f2() { return 2; }
};

// EOF
```

Example invocation:

```
$ make run-quick
./method-decls.exe test.cc
C++ method "C::f1" at test.cc:6:7
C++ method "C::f2" at test.cc:7:7
```