# using libClang or libTooling to list function declarations

Tags: c++, clang-static-analyzer, libclang, libtooling, clang-query

I am developing a windows C++ tool to analyze and mutate C code.  I need help to use libClang or preferably libTooling get a list of C function declarations from a source tree of C files (translation units) with their headers.  Eventually, I would like to transform the C files to add instrumentation points.

I need a good starting point example. I started with an example from [AST matchers and Clang refactoring tools](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/07/29/ast-matchers-and-clang-refactoring-tools/).  This seems like a reasonable jumping off point but I don't know how to actually get the list of function names back to where I can assign them to string variables that I can use in my application.

I think [ASTMatchers](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html) would be the preferred approach to tackle this problem. Shown below I created a simple [clang-query](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/code-quality/static-analysis/writing-new/clang-query.html) example to find all function declarations in a single 'test.c' translation unit.  The simple query ***clang-query> m functionDecl()***.  expression returned a list of underligned function declarations including the return type and arguments.  AST matchers can be easily created from simple clang-query scripts as I understand.

Here is the simple clang-query example of what I would like to achieve in C++:
Using a test file 'test.cpp':

```
// example code
int testFn0(const int* pa, int *pb) {
    return 3;
}

void testFn(const int* pa, int *pb) {
    int t = 0;
    bool a = true;
    bool b = true;
    bool c = true;
    bool d = true;
    if (a && b || !(c ^ d)) {
        t = 0;
    }
}
```

Then using clang-query

```
~/tools$ clang-query test.c --

clang-query> m functionDecl()

Match #1:

/home/jcoffey/tools/test.cpp:3:1: note: "root" binds here
int testFn0(const int* pa, int *pb) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Match #2:

/home/tools/test.cpp:7:1: note: "root" binds here
void testFn(const int* pa, int *pb) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 matches.
```

Comment: This seems like it is very nearly a duplicate of [How to find method declarations in LibTooling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74764286/how-to-find-method-declarations-in-libtooling/76742519).  The solution I posted there seems like it would do what you want, except you'd want to globally replace "CXXMethodDecl" with "FunctionDecl" to report all functions rather than only methods.