# How to configure vscode to find clang libraries

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang, llvm

Following [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72596778) I created a `FindClassDecls.cpp` file and I try to setup a VSCode in macOS to find the required clang headers. So I've tried to add the output of these two commands:

- `llvm-config --cflags` and
- `clang -E - -v < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep "^ /" | grep clang`

to the "includePath" entry in `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`. So my .json looks like this:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/15.0.7_1/include",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/15.0.7_1/lib/clang/15.0.7/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

However, the required headers are still not found:

```c
#include "clang/AST/ASTConsumer.h"
#include "clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendAction.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"
```

Any idea what could be missing?
My environment:

```
> clang --version
Homebrew clang version 15.0.7
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin
```

```
> llvm-config --version --prefix --includedir --libdir --libs
15.0.7
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/15.0.7_1
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/15.0.7_1/include
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/15.0.7_1/lib
-lLLVM-15
```

Comment: I think you also need `llvm-config -cxxflags` and `llvm-config –includedir`

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a CMakeLists.txt for out of the source building

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to pass C flags, C++ flags, include directories and linker flags to have everything working.

In your current setup you might be missing
e.g., `llvm-config -cxxflags` and `llvm-config –includedir`.

Another approach would be to follow the official tutorial https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html. As per the tutorial, you can develop in  a subdirectory of `clang-tools-extra` where it is easier to setup cmake.

If you want to setup as standalone project then, try adapting cmake modules from: https://github.com/philipc/find-class-decls